# solving differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx}=(x+y)\ln(x+y)-1$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

we have got differential equation and need to solve it
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=(x+y)\ln(x+y)-1$$
my attempt 
$$x+y=k$$
$$1+\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dk}{dx}$$
$$\frac{dk}{dx}=k\ln(k)$$
$$\int_{}^{}\frac{dk}{k\ln(k)}=\int_{}^{}dx+c$$
how to solve this integration ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: What is the derivative of the natural logarithm? This should suggest a substitution for your left-hand integral.

Comment: flawless beauty

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$$ \int \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}dx=\ln(f(x))+c . $$